# Keep getting , TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, typeerror

I keep getting the type error but i can't figure out which is causing the problem.
my code is..

```
#import modules needed
from math import sin, pi, sqrt
from cmath import exp
from lab2_q4b import q

#Define constants
lamda=500e-6 #wavelength of the incident light, units in meter
n=10 #number of slits in a dffraction grating
f=1.0 #focal length, units in meter
x=0.1 #width of the screen, units in meter

#Define a new function called qnew, which will be our integrand
def qnew(u):
    return sqrt(q)*exp(1j*2*pi*x*u/(lamda*f))
```

and I run this it gives me the error..

this is the code for q..

```
#Import modules
from math import sin, pi


#Define a function q that takes u as an argument

def q(u): #transmission function 
    d=20e-6 #separation of slits, units in meter
    alpha=pi/d #

    return (sin(alpha*u))**2 #the result of the transmission function
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, and my function q is written in a separate script;

Comment: #Import modules
from math import sin, pi


#Define a function q that takes u as an argument

def q(u): #transmission function 
    d=20e-6 #separation of slits, units in meter
    alpha=pi/d #
            
    return (sin(alpha*u))**2 #the result of the transmission function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this specific piece of `qnew`:

```
sqrt(q)
```

Running this piece of code in isoltation will raise the exception you're seeing:

```
>>> sqrt(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

`q` is a function, so you're trying to take the square root of a function, which of course makes no sense. I'm not sure what you meant to put in its place, but that the area you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would want to change it to:

```
 return sqrt(q(u))*exp(1j*2*pi*x*u/(lamda*f))
```